# Write a function that eats a Nat and returns a (listof Nat) containing the numbers between 1 and n that are divisible by exactly one of 2, 3, and 5

Tags: list, racket

Write a function (fff n) that consumes a Nat and returns a (listof Nat) containing all the numbers between 1 and n that are divisible by exactly one of 2, 3, and 5.

With n = 10, the numbers divisible by at least one of these values are{2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10}.

But 6 and 10 are divisible by two of these numbers. So (fff 10) => (list 2 3 4 5 8 9)

What I have so far is

```
;; q2

;;(divisible? n d) returns true if no remainder exists when d is divided by n
;;divisible?: Nat-> Num
;;Examples

(check-expect (divisible? 8 4) #true )

(define (divisible? n d) (= 0 (remainder n d)))

;;
(define (multiple-235? n)
  (cond
   ((divisible? n 2) #true)
   ((divisible? n 3) #true)
   ((divisible? n 5) #true)))
```

I'm unsure how to set a range of 1 to n to be examined and i'm as well uncertain how to filter the list to only contain values that are divisible by 2, 3 or 5. How do i set it to only be divisible by one of them.

Comment: `(define (fff n) (for/list ((i (in-range 1 (add1 n))) #:when (= (count (λ (d) (zero? (modulo i d))) '(2 3 5)) 1)) i))`

Answer (score 0):

Just use [filter](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._filter%29%29) and fix your `multiple-235?` using PetSerAl's approach (or use his solution):

```
(define (multiple-235? n)
  (= 1 (count (λ (d) (divisible? n d))
              '(2 3 5))))

(define (fff n)
  (filter multiple-235? (range 1 (add1 n))))
```